# Parse a Date from a String in Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a string containing a date, and another string containing the date format of the first string. Is there a function that I can call to convert that date into something like a SYSTEMTIME structure? Basically, I'd like the opposite of [GetDateFormat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776293(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: If you don't want to use MFC you can use VarDateFromStr directly. [VarDateFromStr ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-vardatefromstr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can write a function that will convert the date format string into a `sscanf` format string and series of variables.  Then copy the data from the variables to the `SYSTEMTIME` structure and you're all set.

It's not trivial, but it is probably the most flexible arrangement if you must support many different date formats.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't do quite what you've described, but I'd start by using `COleDateTime::ParseDateTime`. It works with localized date-time formats.

Comment: I saw that function, and given that it doesn't take a format, it seems like it could get confused in some cases (month/day/year vs day/month/year).

Comment: It does take a locale though, so that should help. I can't remember whether it does or not: give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In the source file [Here](http://code.google.com/p/kgui/source/browse/trunk/kgui.cpp).

I have a function that reads dates in a bunch of different formats, the function is called

```
bool kGUIDate::Setz(const char *datestring)
```

It's a class that reads in the day / month / year and also handles hours / minutes / seconds.

The code is LGPL so feel free to copy it.

```
/* formats excepted are: */
/* yyyy-mm-dd */
/* Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT */
/* Wdy, D Mon YY HH:MM:SS GMT */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a POSIX system, you can use the [`strptime()`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_strptime.htm) function.  Unfortunately, MSVC 2005 does not seem to have this function in its C runtime; MinGW for Windows does.

Comment: This has very little to do with the question.

Comment: Totally opposite, its the answer in my opinion.