# Parsing RFC3339 dates in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, winapi

Are there any functions available to parse an RFC3339 date in C++ (even if they are Win32 specific)? I was previously using Qt and the QDateTime::fromString() function to parse the date but I am now using plain old Win32 C++ (No MFC) and I'm struggling to find a way to do it. If there is no standard in way I can write my own but just in case I missed something...

Comment: I stumbled onto this post while looking for a way to parse RFC3339 dates using QDateTime::fromString(). Now that I have the answer, here's the format string you need to use for anyone else who came here for the same reason as me: ""yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zttt"

Answer (score 1):

For parsing and comparing RFC3339 formated dates, you can use [Howard Hinnant's date library.](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)
It can be used as followed:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::istringstream infile{"2005-08-15T15:52:01+04:00"};
    sys_seconds tp;  // This is a system_clock time_point with seconds precision
    infile >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << " is " << tp << '\n';
}
```

A slightly modified versions of "date.h" and "tz.h" were voted into the C++20 working draft.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard api - atleast on windows. I think you'll have to write your own ...

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly looking that way, never mind, shouldn't be too challenging...

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234171/parse-a-date-from-a-string-in-win32 .